# Excel FORECAST function from historical data in multiple row

Tags: excel, excel-formula, forecasting, forecast

```
   A      B      C     D      E      F   ...
-------------------------------------------
1|  QUARTER 1
-------------------------------------------
2|Week    1      2     3      4      5   ...
-------------------------------------------
3|SALES   $500  $300  $100  $280   $600  ...
-------------------------------------------
4|  QUARTER 2
-------------------------------------------
5|Week    14     15    16     17     18   ...
-------------------------------------------
6|SALES   $200  $100  $300   ???
-------------------------------------------
```

I have a similar table that stores the Sales revenue data on a quarterly basis
My problem is that the FORECAST formula doesn't allow me select historical data from 2 rows
I have tried the below formula's:

```
=FORECAST(E6,(B3:N3,B6:N6),(B2:N2,B5:N5))
=FORECAST (E6,(B3,C3,D3,E3...B6,C6,D6),(B2,C2,D2,E2...B5,C5,D5))
```

None of the above worked. What am I doing wrong?

Secondly, is there way to use FORECAST.ETS or similar function in Excel 2013 via other means like vba or other formula?

Lastly, Is it possible to skip/consider Holidays period, where office is closed for over a month?

Answer (score -1):

Following are the changes required in the data and the formulas.

1. (B3:N3,B6:N6) and (B2:N2,B5:N5) are not in one continuous row or column.
   You need to change the way data is entered to B3 to AA3 and B2 to AA2, and then change the corresponding formula to (B3:AA3) and (B2:AA2).
   Even if you use a Name for the range, instead of cell reference, it has to be one continuous range of Row or Column. Blank (and Text) values of Known_Xs and Known_Ys are ignored. However both X and Y ranges have to be equal in length.
2. Your attempt to use the formula using cell names instead of ranges also cannot work. It will work only if cell refences are replaced with values. After you test the formula, select the range, example B3:AA3 and click F9. The cell references will be replaced with numerical values, and the formula will still work.

I hope this will give you a better clarity of what you need to change to make your formula work properly.

Regards,

Vijaykumar Shetye,
Spreadsheet Excellence
Panaji, Goa, India